# node module.export and recursion

Tags: node.js

I am working on a node app that essentially is a simple AWS SQS poller that should sit and listen to new items in different queues.

Here is my `module.export`:

```
module.exports = {
    readMessage: function(qParams, qType, tableName) {
        logger.debug(qType);

        SQS.receiveMessage(qParams, handleSqsResponse);

        function handleSqsResponse (err, data) {
            if(err) logger.error("handleSqsResponse error:" + err);
            if (data && data.Messages) {
                data.Messages.forEach(processMessage)
                readMessage(); // continue reading until draining the queue (or UPTIME reached)
            }
            else{
                logger.debug("no data in sqs.");
                // process.exit();
            }
        }

        // 'processing' is mainly writing to logs using winston. Could add here any transformations and transmission to remote systems
        function processMessage(sqsMessage){
            // Parse sqs messag
            var msgObj = JSON.parse(sqsMessage.Body);

            // Process
            logger.info(msgObj.Message);

            _.extend(qParams, { "ReceiptHandle": sqsMessage.ReceiptHandle });

            dbMap[qType](msgObj, qParams, tableName);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is when I attempt to call `readMessage();` again. I get the error of `ReferenceError: readMessage is not defined`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`module.exports` is a plain object that is exposed to outer modules that has a method `readMessage`. `readMessage()` should be `module.exports.readMessage()`.

Also i would suggest creating a variable and then exporting that:

```
var obj = {
    readMessage: function(qParams, qType, tableName) {
        logger.debug(qType);

        SQS.receiveMessage(qParams, handleSqsResponse);

        function handleSqsResponse (err, data) {
            if(err) logger.error("handleSqsResponse error:" + err);
            if (data && data.Messages) {
                data.Messages.forEach(processMessage)
                obj.readMessage(); // continue reading until draining the queue (or UPTIME reached)
            }
            else{
                logger.debug("no data in sqs.");
                // process.exit();
            }
        }

        // 'processing' is mainly writing to logs using winston. Could add here any transformations and transmission to remote systems
        function processMessage(sqsMessage){
            // Parse sqs messag
            var msgObj = JSON.parse(sqsMessage.Body);

            // Process
            logger.info(msgObj.Message);

            _.extend(qParams, { "ReceiptHandle": sqsMessage.ReceiptHandle });

            dbMap[qType](msgObj, qParams, tableName);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = obj;
```

Please note that I only responded to the question you specifically asked. I didn't take into account any architectural issue associate with the code.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That makes sense! And then I could just pass in the same variables that were passed in originally to the `readMessage()` method?

Comment: That's right... You might wanna add a timer to that but i guess that depends on how often the data is expected to change

Comment: Thanks so much!! You have saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 2):

```
function functionName(has = false){
  var total = 0;
  if(has){
    functionName(true)
  } else {
    // Todo
  }
}

module.exports.functionName = functionName;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.