# How do I include recursive functions in node js from another file

Tags: node.js, recursion

I have the following recursive function saved in a file called helpers.js. When it is loaded into the main app.js file using:

```
var helpers = require('./helpers');
```

calling it only works partially. The line:

```
s+=recurseJSON(o[a]);
```

doesn't get called so the JSON parsing doesn't recurse into nested levels.

I have also tried the following which still doesn't work:

```
s+=helpers.recurseJSON(o[a]);
```

If I move the code below into the main app.js file, the recursion works perfectly, obviously changing

```
recurseJSON: function(o) {...
```

to

```
function recurseJSON(o) {..
```

Your thoughts are appreciated. Here is the whole code:

```
module.exports = {
recurseJSON: function(o){
    var s = '';
    for(var a in o){
        if (typeof o[a] == 'object'){
            s+=a+':';
            console.log('JSON>', a, ":");
            s+=recurseJSON(o[a]);  // This line should recurse but doesn't
        }else{
            s+=a+':'+o[a]+'   ';
            console.log('JSON>', a, ":", o[a]);
        }//end if
    }//end for
    return s;
}
};
```

PS: Credit to [Recursively parsing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104321/recursively-parsing-json) for the original recursive code.

Comment: When a function calls itself, that is _recursive_, not _iterative_. You likely iterate through each key/value pair in JSON, but in a recursive fashion.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26536906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While leaving the export statement like this:

```
module.exports = {
  recurseJSON: function(o){
    ...
  }
};
```

You can call the function recursively using the statement `s+=this.recurseJSON(o[a])`, but only assuming that the only way you invoke the `recurseJSON()` function outside the file is

```
helpers.recurseJSON(obj)
```

so that `recurseJSON()` is the calling member of `helpers`, making the `this` in `recurseJSON()` refer to `helpers`.

If you cannot guarantee this, then the correct way to invoke it, which is more verbose, is

```
s+=module.exports.recurseJSON(o[a])
```

#### Update

Another simpler solution is to just name the function you're exporting:

```
module.exports = {
  recurseJSON: function recurseJSON(o){
    ...
  }
};
```

Then you can just use `s+=recurseJSON(o[a])` like you had before.

Comment: s+=module.exports.iterateJSON(o[a])
 
This worked for me.